# How do I realize a possessive pronoun using the SImpleNLG server?

Tags: xml, simplenlg

My XML looks like this:

```
<Request>
  <Document cat="DOCUMENT">
    <child xsi:type="NPPhraseSpec" PERSON="FIRST">
      <head cat="NOUN">
        <base>hand</base>
      </head>
      <spec xsi:type="WordElement" cat="PRONOUN">
        <base>my</base>
      </spec>
    </child>
  </Document>
</Request>
```

It realizes as "It hand." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello & welcome to stackoverflow! Your question needs more details. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: There are probably not many people here who know NLG well enough to answer, but good luck anyway. However, if your question is "what am I doing wrong", then a good start is to explain in some detail what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.  The pronoun **word** itself can't be possessive.  You have to wrap it in a noun phrase, and set the phrase as possessive.  Then use the possessive noun **phrase** as the specifier of the noun phrase whose head is "hand."  It all makes sense, I just hadn't figured out how to use the framework.